# Invalid relationship

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

I've got a class Account like (in Groovy):

```
@NodeEntity
class Account {
    @GraphId
    Long id

    String accountId
    String firstname
    String lastname

    @Relationship(type = 'HAS_INVITED', direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    List<Account> invitations = []

    String getName() {
        if (firstname && lastname) {
            return "$firstname ${lastname[0]}."
        }

        return email
    }

    @Override
    int hashCode() {
        if (id) {
            return id.hashCode()
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    @Override
    boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj.is(this)) {
            return true
        }

        if (obj instanceof Account) {
            return obj.id == id
        }

        return false
    }

    @Override
    String toString() {
        "$email"
    }
}
```

In my database, I've created 2 accounts Chris and Bob. Bob has invited Chris like below.
[image]

To load accounts, I've written this repository:

```
interface AccountRepository extends GraphRepository<Account> {
    Account findByAccountId(String id)

    Account findByEmail(String email)

}
```

Now, my problem: when I load the Chris account I get Bob as invited (it's ok). But, I've got Chris as invited for Bob and I don't understand why. 
For me, I should have one invitation for Chris but 0 for Bob.

Comment: Do you have a setter for `List<Account> invitations`?  If so it needs to be annotated by @Relationship as well.

Comment: Great! It works.

Answer (score 0):

Any existing setter for INCOMING relationships must be annotated to avoid ambiguity during mapping. This is specified in the documentation:

> The direction attribute on a @Relationship defaults to OUTGOING. Any fields or methods backed by an INCOMING relationship must be explicitly annotated with an INCOMING direction.

http://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:annotating-entities:relationship

Comment: I've missed the point fields AND setter methods must be annoted.